# change string new date to date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have string date like

> 'new Date(0,0,0,11,13,16)'

and want to change it to

> new Date(0,0,0,11,13,16)

anyone have an idea on it.

thanks

Comment: It is not clear what it is you want to achieve. If you want to edit some parts of a string you can use slice or replace. if you want your string to become code you can use eval.

Comment: `const string = '\'new Date(0,0,0,11,13,16)\''; string.substring(1, string.length - 1);`

Comment: @Xatenev thanks but not working

Comment: @rustypaper actually my I am trying to add values in HTML string in node js project and rendering html with API response so my date is in string like 'new date(0,0,0,11,13,16)' so I want to remove " ' " from string to make actual date

Comment: Still, it's not clear why you're in this situation to begin with. Its seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Right now, it seems that you shouldn't be generating those strings that way. Either generate them without the extra quites or probably better - don't generate *code as a string*.

Comment: @vlaz i am trying to make my array like [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ] and rendring html and my HTML is string html

Comment: That doesn't make the requirement and solution any clearer...

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = 'new Date(0,0,0,11,13,16)';        
var str1 = str.match(/\(.*\)/g)[0];        
str1 = str1.replace('(', '');        
str1 = str1.replace(')', '');        
var dateArr = str1.split(',');        
var updatedDate = new 
Date(dateArr[0],dateArr[1],dateArr[2],dateArr[3],dateArr[4],dateArr[5]);        
console.log(updatedDate);
```

Comment: thanks but I want to place date inside [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ] so right now my date is inside quotes like 'new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0,0) ' and I want new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0,0)

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to solve this problem by matching only numbers. `match` will return an array of numbers so use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to set all the parameters to Date.

```js
const res = new Date(...'new Date(0,0,0,11,13,16)'.match(/[0-9]+/g));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I don't want to convert into date I just want to remove quotes from string

Comment: @kalpeshR I'm confused. You can't remove the quotes... without making it into a date...

Comment: here is my array [[ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ]] and I have date inside quote so I want to remove quote

Comment: The example you provide are actual dates and not a string.

Comment: yes @kemicofa but  my code is like  "dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ]])" inside string so I want to change data inside string, i have changed data but date is saving as string

Comment: @kalpeshR in any case you can't simply remove the ""s and hope for it to work. You have to either create a date or keep it as a string.

Comment: this library want array like new Date() from https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#controlling-the-colors

Comment: I am rendersing same code as HTML response from REST API

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could use the `eval` function for that.

Depending on the use, this does propose some security risk though. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

If it's possible I would suggest you use another form of date string, e.g. "yyyy-mm-dd" (2019-02-17) and parse it to a date object using the `new Date(dateString) constructor` (`new Date('2019-01-17')`).